# post to friends feed facebook without feed dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, blackberry, blackberry-cascades

I'm creating an app using Facebook API in cascades BB 10. I have done the login part in C++ using qnetwork manager. I was able to post to my wall using HTTP post with graph API. I want to post to my friends wall. After searching, I found that it is not possible using graph API but only with feed dialog. As I'm not using any SDK, is there any other option for posting to friends wall?

Comment: No there is no other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But some other options (since your req could be batch post) you may like, such as:

You can post feed/photo on the user's wall and tag the friend/s in that post using `mention tagging` or `place` parameter

Read more about tagging on the developers site here: [Tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/)

Comment: I want to say "Happy Birthday" to friends.so tagging will not be appropriate.I have seen apps like EasilyDo which even schedule birthday post and post it at a particular time.any idea how it is done? I'm new to facebook api.what about opengraph?

Comment: How is that app doing? Can you post some screenshots.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, this app has also used the `mention tagging`. The post is not published on the friend's wall, instead it is published on the user's wall with the friend tagged

Comment: oh.I'm new to facebook api itself.can you give me some links on how to use mention tagging in opengraph